# Create file in all subdirectories

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm trying to create a file called `1` in all subdirectories.
e.g the main directory is `abc` and sub-directories are `abc/xyz`, `abc/ghi/123`

It must contain a full path and file name.

Comment: Files should be like: `abc/xyz/1` , `abc/ghi/1` ,  `abc/ghi/123/1` ?

Comment: Name of the file should be `1`. For example if it in `abc/xyz/` it must contain text like:
`abc/xyz/`
`1`

Comment: Actually I meant you needed file name `1` everywhere i.e. in location `abc/ghi` and  `abc/ghi/123/ ` separately or only in end folders(leaf nodes).

Comment: Evereywhere, yes like in `abc/ghi` and  `abc/ghi/123`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use:

```
find abc -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do
      readlink -f "$dir"/1 > "$dir"/1
done
```

1. It finds all directories recursive in directory named `abc`
2. For each directory found, it read it to "dir" variable
3. `readlink -f` shows full path to a path "$dir"/1
4. `> "$dir"/1` writes to the file `"$dir"/1`, truncates it before writing, creates if it does not exists
5. The `-print0` and `-d ''` are for handling spaces and newlines in directory names.

And a version using xargs:

```
find abc -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -- sh -c 'readlink -f "$1"/1 > "$1"/1` --
```

But we can also use find's -exec, which should probably be the fastest:

```
find abc -type d -exec sh -c 'readlink -f "$1"/1 > "$1"/1' -- {} \;
```

Comment: Why the downvote. It would definitely be pleasant if the downvoter would care to contribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along the lines of

```
for d in $(find abc -type d); do
    touch "$d"/1
done
```

Comment: Maybe that could be a `touch` instead of `mkdir`

Comment: My bad. I thought user wanted to create a dir instead of file. Will fix it now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you for response, but how could I put a text in each `1` file?

Comment: echo "${d}/1" > "$d"/1 . Will do the trick.